# Scheme: how to convert a char to a number/string

Tags: string, char, numbers, scheme, type-conversion

I am pulling my hair out right now. I am trying to check if a value (which happens to be a char that is the number 5) is a number by comparing it like

```
(number? (string->number (list->string nextchar)))
```

but I keep getting an error of:

```
list->string: contract violation
   expected: (listof char?)
  given: #\5
```

How can I convert a char to a number, as well as to a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `string` function to convert the char to a string:

```
> (number? (string->number (string #\5)))
#t
```

But it would be better to test directly that the char is numeric:

```
> (char-numeric? #\5)
#t
```